# How to run a command when clicking submit button (lua)?

Tags: lua, cgi

i want to use lua to generate cgi-webpages with uhttpd. What's the correct way to execute a shell command when a button (submit form), or a link is clicked?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for the specifics of what form the HTML would take and the server side scripts in order to do what you want, then your question is way too broad. If you're just wondering about the Lua side of running shell command:

The HTTP GET (link click) or POST (form) would cause one of your Lua functions to get called, wherein you would call os.execute('your-command'). However, due to the obvious security risk associated with calling os.execute, some environments that embed Lua disable certain calls. I don't know anything about the Lua modules allowed by uhttpd. With some luck, it supports the call, and it's up to you to make the proper checks if you want to use it.